# JAVA SE 8, JDK-8u151.exe installation doesn't include src.zip file

Tags: java, java-8

I have started to work with java 8 and for that i have installed java SE 8 update 151 (i.e., jdk-8u151-windows-x64.exe)

I expect post installation of this java 8 , i should be able to see src.zip file in my corresponding jdk folder so that i could see how the internals of java api works(i.e., attach java8 api source in my eclipse ).

I don't see src.zip file present in my jdk folder. I tried googling for the solution but i did not get any relevant solutions . 
Can anybody please tell me how to get java 8 api source zip file for the corresponding version(jdk-8u151)

Comment: @user3382203. While installing above mentioned jdk , i don't see any related installation wizard though.

Comment: Alternatively , i had preferred to install jdk silently by following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#jdk-silent-installation) .     i have used following command to install java 8 to include source zip file also . 
    jdk-8u151-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature"  .

Comment: **Note** : jdk-8u151-windows-x64.exe file should be present directory from where your excuting the command.